# how to stop AppWidgetProvider autoupdate every 30 min in android

Tags: android, eclipse, widget

how to stop AppWidgetProvider autoupdate every 30 min in android background , in my case my widget data is update after every 30 min i want to disable that , i only want that when user click on refresh buttion then only data will update , not every 30 min

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [app widget metadata](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData), set `android:updatePeriodMillis` to `0`.